# Dragonegg on Mac OS X Issues

Tags: macos, gcc, llvm

I'm trying to get dragonegg built and running on my mac.  Using LLVM 3.5 and gcc 4.8, from the homebrew package manager.

Compiling dragonegg in per the readme (`GCC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8 LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/local/bin/llvm-config-3.5 make`) ends with this error:

```
Compiling Cache.cpp
/Users/aelberg/Development/dragonegg-3.5.0.src/src/Cache.cpp:243:15: error: no matching function for call to 'operator new'
  WeakVH *W = new (&(*slot)->V) WeakVH(V);
              ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: candidate function not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
1 error generated.
make: *** [Cache.o] Error 1
```

This seems to relate to the libc++ vs. libstdc++ issues that have been a problem compiling on the mac.  And dragonegg *will* compile with `GCC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8 LLVM_CONFIG=/usr/local/bin/llvm-config-3.5 LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib/ -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib/llvm-3.5/usr/lib" CXX="/usr/local/bin/clang++-3.5 -stdlib=libc++" CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/local/lib/llvm-3.5/include/c++/v1"  make`

However, when I attempt to use dragonegg to compile anything, I get this unfortunate set of errors:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8 -fplugin=/usr/local/lib/dragonegg_483_35.so hello.c
/var/folders/s1/_v14lsc56tv44hm304m07vn40000gq/T//ccPKylId.s:2:Unknown pseudo-op: .macosx_version_min
/var/folders/s1/_v14lsc56tv44hm304m07vn40000gq/T//ccPKylId.s:2:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 49 (1).
/var/folders/s1/_v14lsc56tv44hm304m07vn40000gq/T//ccPKylId.s:9:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_startproc
/var/folders/s1/_v14lsc56tv44hm304m07vn40000gq/T//ccPKylId.s:12:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_def_cfa_offset
/var/folders/s1/_v14lsc56tv44hm304m07vn40000gq/T//ccPKylId.s:12:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 49 (1).
/var/folders/s1/_v14lsc56tv44hm304m07vn40000gq/T//ccPKylId.s:14:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_offset
/var/folders/s1/_v14lsc56tv44hm304m07vn40000gq/T//ccPKylId.s:14:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 37 (%).
/var/folders/s1/_v14lsc56tv44hm304m07vn40000gq/T//ccPKylId.s:17:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_def_cfa_register
/var/folders/s1/_v14lsc56tv44hm304m07vn40000gq/T//ccPKylId.s:17:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 37 (%).
/var/folders/s1/_v14lsc56tv44hm304m07vn40000gq/T//ccPKylId.s:72:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_endproc

$ /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8 hello.c

$ ./a.out
Hello World
```

This, obviously, seems unlikely to involve any of the settings in the compiler flags used to create dragonegg, since they all relate to C++.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is to tell dragonegg to use llvm's assembler rather than the system assembler by adding `-specs=[path to integrated=as.specs]`.  Per dragonegg's documentation this should neither be necessary, nor work, but it does.